# .htaccess убрать дубли со слэшем и без

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать переадресации:

1) если адрес заканчивается на .html и есть / в конце - то убрать / в конце.

2) если адрес не заканчивается на .html (каталог) и нет / в конце - дописать / в конце.

Нашел пару похожих примеров и совместил их. Что-то не так с синтаксисом и мозг упорно отказывается вникать в дебри синтаксиса htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|.[a-zа-я]{2,5})$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|.[a-zа-я]{2,5})$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Подскажите!

Answer (score 2):

Начало файла `.htaccess`, убирающее `/` у адреса, заканчивающегося на `\.html`, будет таким:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)\/$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

А дальше у Вас написано немного неоднозначно, поэтому приведу все возможные варианты.

Добавление `/` к **любому** адресу, не оканчивающемуся на `.html` и не имеющего `/` в конце:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Добавление `/` к адресу, не имеющему `/` в конце и указывающему на каталог:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [L,R=301]
```

А если надо добавлять `/` к любому адресу, не оканчивающемуся на `.html`, не имеющего `/` в конце и указывающему на каталог, то и начало несколько изменится:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)\/$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [L,R=301]
```